# Omitting the subject between

Tags: ellipsis, parallelism

> I can do this one but am not sure about the other.

Can I say the sentence above? Or I have to say "...this one but **I** am not...", but using two I's seems a bit redundant, on the other hand omitting it seems a bit strange.

Can I add a comma?

> I can do this one, but am not sure about the other.

Other than the grammar question, how to say this smoothly?

Comment: Stick with **I'm** in the second coordinate. That's the most natural and better-sounding option.

Answer (score 2):

You need the subject, so *I am* is correct, but it is more colloquial to use *I'm* (because it flows better):

> I can do this one, but I'm not sure about the other.

I am not saying that you can *never* omit the subject, but it would sound a little clunky in this case.

Answer (score 1):

> I can do this one but am not sure about the other.

That sentence sounds perfectly acceptable to me. I am a native speaker of AmE, [Central Atlantic](http://www.daredictionary.com/?region=C%20Atl#entriesList) region per D.A.R.E.