# What is the correct usage of the verb "to be" in the following sentence?

Tags: verbs

Is it correct to say, "I sent them an email **and am** waiting to hear back" or "I sent them an email **and I'm** waiting to hear back"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["And am happy" is correct or not in this context?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/215679/and-am-happy-is-correct-or-not-in-this-context) And probably many others, including [Verb “to be” without a subject not allowed?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/147851/verb-to-be-without-a-subject-not-allowed) and [Omitting the subject between](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/118265/omitting-the-subject-between) (yeah - that's the entire title! :)

Answer (score 2):

You do understand, I hope, that "I'm" is simply a contraction of "I am" and represents absolutely no difference in meaning, grammar, or comprehensibility. It is true that that the use of contractions is frowned upon in formal writing, but there is no valid argument that contractions are not grammatical and idiomatic.

> I sent them an email and am waiting to hear back

is grammatical and idiomatic as are both

> I sent them an email, and I am waiting to hear back

and

> I sent them an email, and I'm waiting to hear back

All three mean exactly the same thing.